# How to deploy docker file on other server

Tags: node.js, express, docker, mongoose

I am trying to deploy docker container to other server.

Here code is, in which some files

server.js

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var halson = require('halson'); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/product_quantities"); 
var ProductQuantity = require('./app/models/product_quantity');
var router = express.Router(); 
router.put('/product_quantities/:product_id', function(req, res) {
if (req.body.quantity_onhand == null) {
    res.status(400);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.error+json');
    res.json({ message: "quantity_onhand parameter is required"});
}  
else{
    ProductQuantity.findOne({ product_id: req.params.product_id}, function(err, productQuantity) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        var created = false; // track create vs. update
        if (productQuantity == null) {
            productQuantity = new ProductQuantity();
            productQuantity.product_id = req.params.product_id;
            created = true;
        }
        // set/update the onhand quantity and save
        productQuantity.quantity_onhand = req.body.quantity_onhand;
        productQuantity.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500);
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.error+json');
                res.json({ message: "Failed to save productQuantity"});
            } else {
                // return the appropriate response code, based
                // on whether we created or updated a ProductQuantity
                if (created) {
                res.status(201);
                } else {
                res.status(200);
                }

                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/hal+json');

                var resource = halson({
                    product_id: productQuantity.product_id,
                    quantity_onhand: productQuantity.quantity_onhand,
                    created_at: productQuantity.created_at
                }).addLink('self', '/product_quantities/'+productQuantity.product_id)

                res.send(JSON.stringify(resource));
              }

          });
      });
   }    
 });
// Register our route
 app.use('/', router);

// Start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Running on port ' + port);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
      "express": "^4.15.2",
      "halson": "^2.3.1",
      "mongoose": "^4.9.3"
  }
```

}

config.js

```
 module.exports = {
    db: {
     production:     "mongodb://"+process.env.MONGODB_ADDRESS+":27017/product_quantities",
  development:   "mongodb://"+process.env.MONGODB_ADDRESS+":27017/product_quantities",
 }
};
```

dockerfile

```
 FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app  
WORKDIR /usr/src/app  
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080   
RUN npm install  
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

service.yml file

```
 services:

   inventory:
    git_url: git@github.com:launchany/microservices-node-inventory.git
    git_branch: master
    command: npm start
    build_root: .
  ports:
    - container: 8080
     http: 80
     https: 443
  env_vars:
    NODE_ENV: production

 databases:
   - mongodb
```

I have Implemented docker image on local by docker command and also pushed on docker hub.

Now In other server when we pull container from docker hub by docker pull command it is successfully run but when we run command of docker then it

return error is:

> > MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Comment: Check to see if your mongo db container has port 27017 exposed. Are you using linux/docker or windows/docker?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont have a mongoDB running. Do you have a local Mongo installation or is it containerized too?

If yes, make sure that a Mongo instance is also running on your server.

Answer (score 0):

In `server.js` you have:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/product_quantities");
```

In your `config.js` you're exporting the prod and dev urls for the mongodb connection string but doesn't seem like you use that anywhere in your code so you are always loading the localhost connection string.

In your code you need to use the values from the `config.js` and in the dockerfile, set the environment value for `MONGODB_ADDRESS`